# How to avoid inserting two time in double click time in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am search the other result of related question and that i implement in my code but that not working ,i have 2 button in a form

my form

```
<form id="InVoice" action="<?php echo  base_url('Staff/add_invoice_spare');?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">


    /*-- content herer--*/


<button style="float:right;" type="submit" name="ready" value="Ready For Bill" class="btn btn-danger" style="border-radius:60px;">Add to Ready for Bill</button>

<button style="float:right;margin-left:15px;" type="submit" name="print" class="btn btn-danger" style="border-radius:60px;">Print</button>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

and used script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#InVoice").submit(function() {
        alert();
        $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled',true);
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

this my controller for inserting

```
public function add_invoice_spare()
  {
   $bill=$this->input->post('ready');
    if($bill)
    {
    $reg=$this->input->post('rno');
        $data=array(
              /*-----------datas here-----*/
                   );
    $ans=$this->Bill_model->check_registration($reg);
    $form_data=  $this->input->post();
    $result=$this->Bill_model->invoice_dtls_ready($form_data,$data);
        if($result){
                    redirect('Staff/list_invoice/'.$result);
                   }
    }else{
            $reg=$this->input->post('rno');
            $data=array(
              /*-----------datas here-----*/
                        );
            }
                $form_data=  $this->input->post();
                $result=$this->Bill_model->invoice_dtls($form_data,$data);
            if($result)
            {
            ?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
        window.open('invoice_pdf/<?PHP echo $result ?>', '_blank');
        window.location.href = "invoice_labour";
</script>
    <?php   }
        }
}
```

but in double click or single click the **Add to Ready for Bill** button the print button is work why that redirect?

any way to solve this issue and only one time submitte the data ?
thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Change this `$("form#InVoice").submit(function() {` to this `$("form#InVoice").submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault();`

Comment: try this <button ype="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true" value="Save"/></button>

Comment: @hungrykoala  the redirect issue is solve but the double click and double entry is not solved

Comment: also, change your button type to a button instead of submit. Since you're using jquery to submit your form anyway.

Comment: We can't know what's happening for you double entry until you post your insert code.

Comment: @user200 button disabled but function not run

Comment: @hungrykoala ok Waite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the buttons that you are clicking on are of the type submit or they are submit buttons. So the only way to differentiate this will be at the backend.

For eg, according to the above example when you submit the `$_POST` array will have the submit button value. It is based on this value that you have to build your code logics.

If you click on Print then `$_POST['submit']` will be the value will be print and when you click on "Add to Ready for Bill" the `$_POST['submit']` value will be ready.

If you want to control it in the Frontend i.e., jQuery end you can by using the preventDefault (the example of which is given by @pradeep) but I suggest you modify the Backend as well to differentiate between these 2 submit buttons.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i will post by name and check  but why insert two time in double click time